# AWS Api-Gateway error 500 on postman / success on api gateway test

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I am facing a strange issue with a lambda intergration in api gateway ( tried proxy as well same issue)

lambda first hits AppSync and  returns either  JSON content on error or a XLXS file on success.

while testing on API gateway test console it brings back status 200 and the binary results as expected. but when i try it externally through postman it fails.

More info :

Intergration type : Lambda

Success response :

```
response = buffer.toString("base64");
```

Error Response:

```
response= JSON.stringify(err);
```

Serverless apigateway setup:

```
exportXls: 
handler: ./src/apiGatewayLambdas/exportxls/exportXls.handler
role:  AppSyncLambdaRole 
events:
    - http:
        path: /api/exportxls
        method: post
        integration: lambda

        contentHandling: CONVERT_TO_BINARY
```

Comment: What are you sending via Postman? Have you checked the Lambda logs? :)

Comment: Here is the weird thing that i get no error logs... i only see logs on success from the test console. and few logs i managed to get on cloudwatch they all bring up 
Sat Jun 06 14:46:31 UTC 2020 : Successfully completed execution
Sat Jun 06 14:46:31 UTC 2020 : Method completed with status: 200
( tested just now)

Comment: Right, have you got API Gateway logs enabled, that might help?

Comment: yes the error here after lambda execution success : 
Method request body before transformations: [Binary Data]
Execution failed due to configuration error: Unable to transform request

Comment: Presumably caused by `contentHandling: CONVERT_TO_BINARY`

Comment: this is a serverless plugin to enable the convertion . i tried removing it as well and setting explicitly   content type and content-disposition but the same issue occurs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently  Apigateway with lambda or proxy integration  encodes body to base64. so i changed my lambda to

```
let buffer = new Buffer(_event.body, "base64");
let body = buffer.toString("ascii");
body = JSON.parse(body);
```

and everything  worked as expected .